# Spring Boot 2.2 Management Endpoints not working with external Jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty, spring-actuator

After migrating from spring boot 2.0.4 to Spring boot 2.2.13 with management port different than the server port, the management endpoints stopped working. it looks like the different management port itself is not opened for listening.

while it does not work when deploying as a war to external jetty it does work well when running as embedded jetty.

below is the relevant yml part:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health
      base-path: /manage
    enabled-by-default: true
  server:
    port: 7080
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot does not support running the management server on a separate port when deployed to an external container. You should use an embedded web server if you want the management endpoints to be available on a separate port.

Comment: I figured that was the issue. But it did work with Spring boot 2.0 so I thought it is a migration problem

Comment: I don't think it can have worked with 2.0. Spring Boot has never supported running the management server on a separate port when deployed to an external container.